# Android - Why is using onSaveInsanceState() to save a bitmap object not being called?

Tags: android, bitmap, savestate

I'm making a simple drawing application.

I want to be able to save the user's drawing on the screen when the device orientation changes. This only happens in the main activity.

I read that if the orientation changes, then the activity is destroyed and recreated again (`onCreate(Bundle created)` being called).
I'm not sure if it means that it should also call `onSavedInstanceState(Bundle bundle)`, because in my app it is only called if another activity takes the focus on top of my main activity, but not when rotating to landscape/portrait.

I'm simply looking for a way to save an existing bitmap and pass it to the main activity when the orientation changes. How can I do it if my `onSaveInstanceState` never gets called?

Also, since Bitmap implements `parceable` already I used it.

Here's the code from the main activity:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
// some more activity code...

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bitmap = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
        Log.d("STATE-RESTORE", "bitmap created");
        paintBoard.setBitmapBackground(bitmap, false);
        Log.d("RESTORING...", "onRestoreInstanceState()");
    } else {
        Log.d("SavedInstanceState", "null");
    }
}


// Never called when I change orientation on my device
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(paintBoard.getBitmap());
    outState.putParcelable("bitmap", bitmap);
    Log.d("STATE-SAVE", "onSaveInstanceState()");
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

**EDIT :**

I removed this line from the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and now `onSaveInstanceState()` does get called when I change orientation on the device.

Comment: If you solved your problem, then I think you should probably write your solution down here.

Comment: Well, it solved half of the problem. onSaveInstanceState() gets called now, but can't figure out how to pass my Bitmap object when the activity is created again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should read [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) completely.

> ...it might not be possible for you to completely restore your
>   activity state with the Bundle that the system saves for you with the
>   `onSaveInstanceState()` callback—it is not designed to carry large
>   objects (such as bitmaps) and the data within it must be serialized
>   then deserialized, which can consume a lot of memory and make the
>   configuration change slow. In such a situation, you can alleviate the
>   burden of reinitializing your activity by retaining a stateful Object
>   when your activity is restarted due to a configuration change.
>
> To retain an object during a runtime configuration change:
>
> 1. Override the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` method to return the
>      object you would like to retain.
> 2. When your activity is created again,
>      call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to recover your object.

Comment: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is now deprecated.Consider using setRetainInstance(boolean retain)

Answer (score 6):

I'm going through the Android tutorials from TheNewBoston https://thenewboston.com/

In the 4th section, Travis walked us through making a Camera application which can set a picture as wallpaper as well. The problem with the vanishing bitmap on rotation wasn't resolved however, he only offered the `android:configChanges="orientation"` solution, which blocks the screen rotation temporarily.

Using the information from this page, I added

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    bmp = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

at the end of the onCreate

and added this override

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putParcelable("bitmap", bmp);
}
```

in the class.

This solved the problem of the vanishing bitmap.

Comment: Is that approach good with regard to memory consumption? When this bitmap will be deleted from memo?

Comment: Don't store bitmaps in bundles. It can give you `TransactionTooLargeException`.

Answer (score 0):

An onConfigurationChanged() method would probably be the simplest solution to your problem.
It saves the apps current state between orientation switches

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) has more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Now, you can store your data in view models and keep them across configuration changes.

Answer (score -14):

Save your bitmap in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` because i think `onSavedInstanceState()` is never called by the android sytem when switching orientation.

Comment: I found the problem. The reason `onSaveInstanceState()` was never called, is because I added this line to the AndroidManifest.xml file: `android:configChanges="orientation"`, which as far as I know, is intended to deal with events line orientation change and sliding hardware keyboard manualy for better performance.

Removing this line fixed the problem.

Comment: I have found that onSavedInstanceState() is absolutely called on device rotation.